# How to test widget that is instantiated in didUpdateWidget() in Flutter?

Tags: asynchronous, testing, flutter, widget

I have a StatefulWidget that creates an `AnimatedCrossFade` widget in `didUpdateWidget()`, and saves it as `animation`. Here's a pared down example:

```
class BackgroundImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color colorA;
  final Color colorB;

  const BackgroundImage({
      this.colorA,
      this.colorB,
  });
}

class _BackgroundImageState extends State<BackgroundImage> {
  Widget _animation;

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Widget old) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(old);
    _buildBackgroundA(colorA).then((backgroundA) {
      _buildBackgroundB(colorB).then(backgroundB) {
        print(backgroundA); // this is not null
        print(backgroundB); // this is not null
        _animation = AnimatedCrossFade(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 15),
          firstChild: backgroundA,
          secondChild: backgroundB,
          crossFadeState: someVarToSwitchColors,
              ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
              : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
          );
       }
     }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _animation != null ? _animation : Container();
  }
}
```

`_buildBackgroundA()` and `_buildBackgroundB()` are async functions that reuturn `Future<Widget>`. This works fine in my app - `didUpdateWidget()` is called, my `AnimatedCrossFade` shows up and animates between the two backgrounds.

However, I'm having trouble finding `AnimatedCrossFade` in my test. I'm able to find my other Stateless widgets, and also able to find the `BackgroundImage` widget. I have something like:

```
    await tester.pump();
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(minutes: 1));
    expect(
        find.descendant(
            of: find.byType(BackgroundImage),
            matching: find.byType(AnimatedCrossFade)),
        findsOneWidget);
```

This fails as it can't find `AnimatedCrossFade`.

If I change my `build()` function to:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedCrossFade(...);
  }
```

I'm able to find my widget. So I suspect it has something to do with my test `expect` executing before my `_buildBackground()` functions are done. I've tried altering the duration in my `pump` and `pumpAndSettle` to no effect. How do I force the test to wait more? Is there something else I'm missing?

The test log looks like this (with my prints):

```
Running Flutter tests.
00:00 +0: ...d/work/.../cl00:00 +0: (setUpAll)                                                                                                          00:00 +0: Test background                                              
init state called
_buildBackgroundA called
init state called
_buildBackgroundB called
...
00:00 +0 -1: Test background
    Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
    Actual: ?:<zero widgets with type "AnimatedCrossFade" that has ancestor(s) with type "BackgroundImage" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
     Which: means none were found but one was expected
  This was caught by the test expectation on the following line:
 ...line 179

about to return from calling _buildBackgroundA
image: Image(image: MemoryImage(_Uint8ArrayView#af55b, scale: 1.0), width: 50.0, height: 200.0, fit: cover, alignment: center, this.excludeFromSemantics: false, filterQuality: low)
about to return from calling _buildBackgroundB
image: Image(image: MemoryImage(_Uint8ArrayView#79291, scale: 1.0), width: 50.0, height: 830.0, fit: cover, alignment: center, this.excludeFromSemantics: false, filterQuality: low)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to test `didUpdateWidget` as a separate method. So, first we need to know that when are the times `didUpdateWidget` will be called inside flutter.

1. When the widget's parent rebuilds: If a widget's parent rebuilds due to some changes, the framework will also rebuild the widget. This will trigger the `didUpdateWidget` method to be called with the new widget.
2. When the widget is rebuilt with new parameters: If the StatefulWidget is rebuilt with new parameters, the framework will call the didUpdateWidget method. This is because the widget has changed, and it might need to update its internal state to reflect the new parameters.
3. When the widget is rebuilt with the same parameters: If the StatefulWidget is rebuilt with the same parameters, the framework will call the `didUpdateWidget` method. This is because the widget has changed, and it might need to update its internal state even if the parameters are the same.

So, if you are testing a widget which doesn't have a parent while testing. Wrap it with StatefulBuilder and change the variable you are passing to the widget with any way to test if the `didUpdateWidget` is working or not.

I will give an example for that to give an idea how to do in your code.

```dart
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          theme: AppThemes.theme(themeMode: ThemeMode.light),
          home: Scaffold(
            body: StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context,setState) {
                return GiftWrap(
                  title: titleString,
                  subTitle: "You Have 0 Loyalty Point.",
                  icon: Icons.info_outline,
                  iconLabel: "Redeem Now",
                  iconPath: loyalPointIconPath,
                  onTap: (redeem) {
                    setState((){
                      titleString = "Loyalty";
                    });
                  },
                );
              }
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

If you have any more doubt. Then comment below.